# Is there a limit to cloud servers I can own?

Tags: blockheads

On Blockheads, it is possible to create a server that others can join.

Is there a limit to the amount of servers I can have?

Comment: What is that character between "to" and "servers"?

Comment: @T.J.L. it's a "cloud" emoji. I'm not sure about its significance...

Comment: @antimo Ah... I see it now. Hopefully, the querent will come back and clarify. If it's just to be cute, it's bad form because it's not easily typable which means it's not likely to be a search hit.

Comment: @T.J.L. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no limit to the mount of servers you can have. All you need is a lot of time crystals if you want to have a lot of servers.